# Upper d-Ahlfors measure, Hausdoff $N-1$ dimensional measure, usual surface measure

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I'd like to know the relation between **Upper d-Ahlfors measure** , **Hausdorff $N-1$ dimensional measure** and **usual surface measure**.

(1) Let $\Omega$ be a smooth bounded domain. Then, on $\partial \Omega,$ do two measures coincide with the usual surface measure?

(2) Are there any relations about 3 measures above?

I would be grateful for any comment about it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the open set, then they coincide on the bounduary since it is rectifiable (to be fair its reduced bounduary is rectifiable).

I think in general knowing that your surface is the bonduary of an open set does not give you any further information and I think it may be possible they differ.

A little remark: on rectifiable sets all reasonable surface measures coincide.

Comment: In first paragraph, do you mean for a smooth bounded domain, they are all coincide on its boundary?

Comment: no I mean finite perimeter in the De Giorgi's sense, which means rectifiable bounduary (I wrote finite perimeter, but obviously the same is true for locally finite).

Comment: In first paragraph, if open set has finite perimeter in the De Giorgi's sense~~Is it right?

Comment: no it is not. indeed if you go further the first paragraph, you'll notice I specify that your claim (1) shold be false. Only knowing some regularity of the bonduary can make you be sure those measures coincide. Recall that even standard haudorff measure and the spherical one differ on general Borel sets. In the case your open set is not somehow smooth you "usual surface measure" makes even no sense, since you are implicitely assuming some differentiable structure on the bdry. Take a look to federer's book GMT you'll find lots of inequalities between measures built with Caratheodory costruction

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I will check the book you recommended. By the way, in your answer, the first paragraph was missed something. Due to it, it's hard for me to understand your answer exactly. Also a smooth bounded domain has sufficiently good regularity of its boundary. What regularity of the boundary does we need for coinciding those measures?